# I need to add some form validation for telephone field on admin side for magento

Tags: forms, validation, magento

I need to add some form validation for telephone field on admin side for magento. I am looking for correct file to work on

There's already some validation for required fields on the `admin sales_order_create` I am trying to find the right file that I can work on for the page `sales_order_create`. I did some search but still I had no luck on my code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to class method for validating

```
'validate-phoneStrict'          => 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
'validate-phoneLax'             => 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
```

And this can be use as follow:

```
$fieldset->addField('phone', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('foundation')->__('Phone'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry validate-phoneStrict',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'phone',
            ));
```

Comment: thanks Charlie. which file should I modify to add my validation.

Comment: @mthethelelibeseti, on where and which field you need to add?

Comment: I need to add validation on the Create New Order page for telephone and other fields. But i just need a right direction. i've already got the code

Comment: Create New Order? Can you send me the menu direction where I can get this form

Comment: it under Sales > Orders > then on the right side you will see "Create New Order" button which will lead to the create new order page.